# Reference the data in a column format

Tags: kendo-grid

Here I am formatting a couple of columns, but I have to repeat the field names (`MyDate`,`MyDate2`) inside the template in order to get the data.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: data
    },
    columns: [
        { field: "MyDate",
          title: "My Date",
          template: "#=kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(new Date(MyDate)), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')#" },
        { field: "MyDate2",
          title: "My Date 2",
          template: "#=kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(new Date(MyDate2)), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')#" }
    ]
 });
```

I want to be able to define the template elsewhere:

```
var dateTemplate =
     "#=kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(new Date(?)), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')#"

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: data
    },
    columns: [
        { field: "MyDate",
          title: "My Date",
          template: dateTemplate },
        { field: "MyDate2",
          title: "My Date 2",
          template: dateTemplate }
    ]
 });
```

So that I do not need to repeat the column's field name and can reuse templates.

What can I replace `?` with in order to make this work?